# How can I add multiple strings to one text file, and read the all?

Tags: php

I am trying to make a program where I can add things to a list, read things, and clear the list.  I have the clear function working perfectly, however I can't seem to add or read more than 1 line at a time.  I am using `fwrite($handle, $MyString);`  but that replaces everything in the entire file with `$MyString`.  To get the information from the file I am using `$list = fgets($handle);` and then using echo to print it.  This reads the first line in the file only.
Any help?
Thanks!

Getlist code:

```
<?php
$myFile = "needlist.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
$theData = fgets($fh);
fclose($fh);
echo $theData;
?>
```

Add to the list code:

```
<?php
$neededlist = "needlist.txt";
$fh = fopen($neededlist, 'w');
$user_message = $_REQUEST['txtweb-message'];
$needed .= $user_message;
$needed .= "\n";
fwrite($fh, $needed);
fclose($fh);
echo "You have successfully added ", $user_message;
?>
```

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the whole of your code, please?

Comment: `fopen($filename, 'w+')` => `fopen($filename, 'a+')`.

Comment: how are you opening the file ... should be fopen($filename, "a");

Comment: Opening the file with "a" prints nothing, and with "a+" it prints the first line again.

Comment: For adding lines, however, a+ works!

Comment: file_get_contents() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write to the file are you opening your filehandle with the "a" mode option? Opening with "w" or "x" truncates it so you start with a clean file (http://php.net/fopen)

fgets(); reads only until the end of the line ( http://php.net/fgets ). To get the whole file you can try:

```
var $list = "";
var $line = "";
while ($line = fgets($handle)) {
     $list = $list . "\n" . $line;
}
echo $list;
```

You want to add the "\n" because fread doesn't read the linefeeds IIRC. There're also a couple functions that might be more appropriate in this situation like file_get_contents and fread.

Comment: Isn't this the same as `file_get_contents()`?

Comment: Aside from the fact you call file_get_contents with the file name and you call fgets() with the file handle - yeah. Probably better to use file_get_contents and let the interpreter handle the nitty-gritty.

Answer (score 0):

Fgets returns only one string. You should use it in cycle like that:

```
while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
    echo $buffer;
}
```